# Show values in ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I dont know how to show my values in ajax.Here my example

```
function check_valid() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/something',
        datatype : 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function(status) {
            #status = ["1","abcdef"]
            if (status[0] == 1) {
                $("#check").css({
                    "display" : "block"
                });
                $("#com").html("Complete in #{status[1]}").css({
                    "display" : "block"
                });                 
            }
        },
    });
}
```

I want to show `status[1]` in `$("#com")`, but when I run app in sever it just show this:

```
Complete in #{status[1]}
```

I don't know how to show `status[1]` in client. Please help me to fix that. I use ruby on rails. here my html:

```
<p id="com" style="display: none"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to append the value of the variable to the string. Try this:

```
$("#com").html('Complete in #' + status[1]).show();
```

I would also *strongly* suggest you remove `async: false` from your AJAX settings as it is extremely bad practice.

Comment: It work! I don't know I can get values like that, thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function check_valid() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/something',
        datatype : 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function(status) {
            #status = ["1","abcdef"]
            if (status[0] == 1) {
                $("#check").css({
                    "display" : "block"
                });
                $("#com").html("Complete in"+ status[1]).css({"display" : "block"});      //Youre concatination is wrong            
            }
        },
    });
}
```